# Using @ViewChild on a component inside a component getting undefined value

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I'm using Primeng's Listbox and an ngx-bootstrap's dropdown components in my project. I used these components in my project in a way that the Listbox is inside the ngx dropdown.

```
<!--this is a ngx dropdown-->
<ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" >
     <div class="well well-dropdown">Customize Grid</div>

      <!-- this is a primeng listbox -->
         <p-listbox  #listbox [options]="persons"  [filter]="false" [(ngModel)]="selectedPerson" [multiple]="true" [checkbox]="true" [metaKeySelection]="false" [style]="{'max-height':'150px'}">               
         </p-listbox>

</ul>
```

I created a variable in the template (#listbox) so I can access it in my ts. So I was trying to perform @ViewChild but. I always getting undefined.

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit{

 @ViewChild('listbox') mylist: Listbox;


 ngOnInit(){
   console.log(this.mylist);  // ==> getting undefined value
 }

 ngAfterViewInit(){
  console.log(this.mylist); // ==> still getting undefined value

 }
}
```

Take note that I already console it in NgAfterViewInit and still getting undefined value for the ViewChild.

For the purpose of testing, I tried moving the primeng's Listbox out of the ngx dropdown and it has a value. BUt when I try to place the listbox inside the ngxdropdown the the viewChild is undefined. As for my application needs I really need to place the listbox inside the ngx.

Comment: Your listbox is located inside EmbeddedView

Comment: How can I access that in ts the same way I can access using viewchild?

Comment: Try using ViewChildren with valueChanges or setter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46251282/angular-viewchild-fileinput-annotation-is-undefined/46251375#46251375

Comment: I already tried it before @yurzui I tried to console log all the children but the listbox is not there. I can the ngx dropdown but not the listbox